# What's a good open source VoiceXML implementation?

Tags: speech-recognition, voip, ivr, voicexml

I am trying to find out if it's possible to build a complete IVR application by cobbling together parts from open source projects.  Is anyone using a non-commercial VoiceXML implementation to build speech-enabled systems?

Answer (score 6):

I've tried JVoiceXML in the past and had some luck with it.

http://jvoicexml.sourceforge.net/

It's java of course, but that wasn't a problem for my situation.

Answer (score 4):

Voiceglue (http://www.voiceglue.org/) is an implementation of voicexml using openvxi and asterisk. It may be a good option for you, it is GPL licensed.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at OpenVXI, I believe that a number of companies that sell very expensive IVR platforms (such as Avaya) have based their voice browser on it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVXI

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Asterix - http://www.asterisk.org/ for an open source solution.

Comment: Asterisk is not a VoiceXML implementation. Voximal is a module for Asterisk allowing it to support VoiceXML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build an IVR and you're not married to VoiceXML, you might try [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/). They have a simple XML syntax, an awesome REST API, and small-project-friendly pay per minute pricing which lets you concentrate on building your app and not building/hosting telephony infrastructure. I built an [IVR app](http://thislineissecure.com/) using their system a few days and it was a pleasure.